# Iterate/fill column based on row values

Tags: python, pandas

Based on my research I am not supposed to iterate but I am struggling with the right method to do this.

My goal: select specific rows from a table based on the value of a row

**Starting point**

```
data = {0: [
    'a',
    'viper',
    'b',
    'c',
    'cobra',
    'd',
    'e',
    'f'
], 1: [20,52,59,67,11,40,10,60]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 20 |
| viper | 52 |
| b | 59 |
| c | 67 |
| cobra | 11 |
| d | 40 |
| e | 10 |
| f | 60 |

**my query**

Get me the rows that have

- viper
- cobra
- cobra+2 (this is the row that sits 2 rows below the one that has cobra in it)

I think the key point here is the cobra+2 is equivalent to e but I can't look for e. I have to look for cobra+2.

**The end result I am looking for**

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| viper | 52 |
| cobra | 11 |
| e | 10 |

The rows that have either viper or cobra, simplified. But I have got a list of >10 values like viper and cobra which I would like to iterate through. Also for some rows I would not like to have the row that shows viper but the row below the one that shows viper.

So what I am thinking of is having a dictionary with the values (viper, cobra, etc.) and the offsets (0 in most cases but +1 or +2 in others). Then "iterating" through the dictionary.

**What I am doing for a single value**
`row = df[df[0] == 'viper'].index[0]` to determine the row# in integer format
and then iloc to pull the row.

What's the best way here?

Comment: `out = df[df[0].isin(['viper', 'cobra')]`

Comment: that's great. But what if my list is viper, cobra, cobra+2, cobra+3? I am not able to reference "e" and "f" in the above but need the reference to be relative to cobra.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please provide an explicit reproducible example and describe the full logic.

Comment: have edited and added a 'query' and adjusted the output. does that help?

Comment: I reopened and provided an approach for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select for multiple conditions with values being a given number of rows after the match, you could combine multiple [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`numpy.logical_or`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html):

```
import numpy as np

# dictionary of position and values
# 0: ['viper', 'cobra'] -> select rows matching 'viper' or 'cobra'
# 2: ['cobra'] -> select a row 2 positions after a 'cobra'
query = {0: ['viper', 'cobra'], 2: ['cobra']}

# combine the boolean Series with OR
mask = np.logical_or.reduce([df[0].isin(v).shift(k, fill_value=False)
                             for k,v in query.items()])

# perform boolean indexing
out = df[mask]
```

Output:

```
       0   1
1  viper  52
4  cobra  11
6      e  10
```

Intermediates:

```
       0   1  isin(['viper', 'cobra'])+shift(0)  isin(['cobra'])+shift(2)     OR
0      a  20                              False                     False  False
1  viper  52                               True                     False   True
2      b  59                              False                     False  False
3      c  67                              False                     False  False
4  cobra  11                               True                     False   True
5      d  40                              False                     False  False
6      e  10                              False                      True   True
7      f  60                              False                     False  False
```

Comment: This is a great way to think about it. Thank you!! Can I ask a follow up question please? If instead of an exact match via isin() i'd want to find a partial match via say str.contains() what would be the best way? I tried simply replacing the isin(v) with str.contains(v, na=False) but it returns the error: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: No, you'd need to build a single regex, for instance `r'cobra|viper'`. From a list: `import re ; pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, your_list))`. Or loop over the items of the list `np.logical_or.reduce([df[0].str.contains(x).shift(k, fill_value=False) for k,v in query.items() for x in v])`